# taking specific time then output result?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to write a program with c++ which can cout a string like "hello world" after taking specific time.Is it possible?

example:(a program which input a string and then cout it.
Input : 
hello
Output :
(after taking 5 sec)
hello

Comment: Yes it's possible. See [`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

Comment: Look into `sleep`. Although  I'm hesitant to suggest it at all because it's probably the #1 most abused function in the spec.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this can be simply solved by looking into the reference documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++11 solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    using namespace std::literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

Read more http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Answer (score 1):

Very easy, put `sleep(5);`between `std::cin >>` and `std::cout <<`.
Don't forget to include `#include <unistd.h>`.